# Функция CHAR() в языке MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

Привет, знатоки MySQL! Подскажите, пожалуйста, в таком вопросе.

`SELECT CHAR(85,78,73,79,78)` возвращает `UNION`.
А `SELECT USER() CHAR(85,78,73,79,78) ALL SELECT VERSION()` возвращает ошибку.

Как осуществить запрос:
`SELECT USER() UNION ALL SELECT VERSION()`, используя `CHAR(85,78,73,79,78)` вместо `UNION`?

Comment: Выполняйте динамически.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В рамках чистого sql это не выполнимо. Вообще.